# On a unitary automorphic representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

I sometimes come across this notion called "unitary automorphic representation". But I have never seen the precise definition. When they say $(\pi, V)$ is a unitary automorphic representation of a group $G(\mathbb{A})$, does that mean that $\pi$ is unitary as an abstract representation of $G(\mathbb{A})$ (assuming $\pi$ is a smooth automorphic representation, so that the full group $G(\mathbb{A})$ acts) in the sense that the space $V$ of $\pi$ is a Hilbert space with $G(\mathbb{A})$-invariant inner product. Or should I assume that $\pi$ is only pre-unitary in the sense that $\pi$ has only a non-degenerate $G(\mathbb{A})$-invariant inner product but the space $V$ is possibly incomplete?

Also if $(\pi, V)$ is a unitary automorphic representation, can I assume that the space is indeed a subspace of the space of automorphic forms on $G(\mathbb{A})$ instead of subquotient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suspect, there are many implicit assumptions and abuses of language in this terminology.

First, it is *not* safe to assume that an "automorphic" repn of $G(\mathbb A)$ is literally a repn of that topological group. Sometimes, only the finite-prime groups are allowed to act, and at archimedean places one does not have a group representation, but only a $\mathfrak g,K$-module. A reason to want to be able to talk this way is so that the $K$-finite vectors at archimedean places be preserved, which would fail for a genuine group representation (at least if the archimedean groups were non-compact).

Second, "unitary" in these situations is used very casually, so, no, one should not presume that the action is on a Hilbert space. Indeed, the requisite completion(s) to a Hilbert space might wreck other assumptions about $K_v$-finiteness at both archimedean and finite places. That is, at finite places, the usual sense of "smoothness" would be ruined.

Nevertheless, sometimes there is reason to *also* be able to refer to the Hilbert-space completion of a pre-unitary repns of groups, as yet-another less-ambiguous isomorphism-class representative.

In any case, no, unitary automorphic repns need not be sub-representations of the space of automorphic forms. The easiest example is the Eisenstein series for $GL(2)$, with parameters making all the local representations unitary. Then these generate everywhere-locally-unitary (or pre-unitary, as you like) repns, but are not subrepresentations, only *quotients*. This is not a "pathology", any more than  is the presence of continuous spectrum in the first place.

It is true that one can try to squirm out of this situation by trying to make "Hilbert integrals"'s integrands behave as well as do genuine sub-objections, but it really doesn't work out.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Prof. Garrett. Indeed, this is apparently related to my other question I asked    before. Actually, here is another related question. Let $(\pi, V)$ be a (not necessarily irreducible) unitary automorphic representation in the sense that it has a non-degenerate G-invariant Hermitian structure but not assumed to be complete. Is it true that for a subspace $W\subseteq V$, we have $V=W\oplus W^\perp$? It seems your comment to my previous question implies this is true.

Comment: About orthogonal complements: if we further burden "unitary automorphic" with meaning "_admissible_, whether or not irreducible", then, yes, _unlike_ general discussion of orthogonal complements, completeness is unnecessary, perhaps counter-intuitively. But it's about taking advantage of "admissibility", which algebraicizes the question, making it not so much about Hilbert spaces. But, again, there is some danger in making admissibility an only-implicit assumption about "automorphic repn". No guarantee that everyone agrees. (Irreducibles _are_ admissible, by thm of Harish-Chandra, Bernstein.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, again. Could you let me know if there is any literature that proves that unitary + admissible implies complete reducibility?

Comment: Very likely you can prove as an exercise that an admissible $K$-space with inner product, in which $K$ acts unitarily, for compact topological group $K$, with every vector $K$-finite, has the complement property. Do you care about anything more general?

Comment: Thanks, again and again. I greatly appreciate it. So does that mean that for a representation of an adele group to have the complement property, one needs the $K$-finiteness assumption only for a particular $K$, even like a compact $K_v=G(\mathcal{O}_v)$ at one finite $v$?

Comment: If you're looking at repns of the full adele group (nevermind tricks at archimedean places), you need $K_v$-finiteness _everywhere_ locally, or else you're back to the failure of the orthogonal complementing process for uninteresting reasons.

Comment: Indeed, I just found it out in Lemma 9.4 in Jacquet-Langlands. But do you have some other proof in mind? It seems JL does not use K-finiteness